# Como pegar somente um valor de uma variável random e transformá-la em constante?

Tags: java, random, constantes

Como faço para pegar somente um valor de uma variável que utiliza `Random` e armazenar em outra variável? É possível?

Queria armazenar o que vai aparecer para o usuário

```
int cartaUnoPersonagem = new Random().nextInt(personagem.length);
System.out.println("Certo "+nome+", você é um(a):"+personagem[cartaUnoPersonagem]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a palavra-chave `final`:

```
final int cartaUnoPersonagem = new Random().nextInt(personagem.length);
```

Comment: Não necessita dos parênteses, pode usar direto `new Random().nextInt(personagem.length)`: https://ideone.com/MA9DaD

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Valeu, corrigi a resposta.